# Need to get data from previous record in table according to latest record

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a query to get latest data entry from user but now I need to get a another record from same table. I need previous record means latest and the previous record and need some data from previous record row and some from latest.

Below is my code which give me latest record data according to created-date or Required date

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RFI_GetGIGCommunicationLog]
    @IDUPW as int ,
    @IDStatus as int--,
    --@TotalGIGCount as INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select upw.IDUPW,gig.IDGig,gig.Number,gig.DateCreated,gig.DateRequired, Originator.Originator,
    lc.IDLifeCycle,lc.LoggedById,lc.OwnedByID, lc.AssignedToID, lc.LoggedOn,lc.Detail,
    f.IDFunction,f.Name,f.PastTenseFunction,AssignedTo.AssignedBy,LoggedBy.LoggedBy, OwnedBy.OwnedBy from [UserXProjectXWorkFlowUserGroup] upw
    inner join gig on gig.IDUPW= upw.IDUPW
    cross apply (select top 1(lic.idLifecycle),lic.AssignedToID,lic.LoggedByID,lic.OwnedByID,lic.IDLevelXFunction, lic.LoggedOn,lic.Detail from lifecycle lic where gig.IdGIG= lic.IDGIG order by loggedon desc  ) lc

    cross apply (SELECT concat(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as'AssignedBy' FROM [User] u WHERE u.IDUser = lc.AssignedToID) AssignedTo
    cross apply (SELECT concat(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as'LoggedBy' FROM [User] u WHERE u.IDUser = lc.LoggedByID) LoggedBy
    cross apply (SELECT  concat(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as'OwnedBy' FROM [User] u WHERE u.IDUser = lc.OwnedByID) OwnedBy
    cross apply (SELECT  concat(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as'Originator' FROM [User] u WHERE u.IDUser = upw.IDUser) Originator
    inner join levelXfunction lf on lf.IDLevelXFunction= lc.IDLevelXFunction
    inner join [Function] f on f.IDFunction = lf.IdFunction
    where gig.IDUPW= @IDUPW  and upw.active=1 
     AND 1=(
       CASE
        WHEN @IDStatus!=0 AND f.IDFunctionXTab= @IDStatus THEN 1
        WHEN @IDStatus=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END
      )
END
```

Comment: Your question is *really* unclear - "i need previous record means latest" suggests there's only one row involved (which you sometimes call latest and sometimes call previous).

Comment: yes this is my latest row according to the date but  i need another row means which is second  latest record and some dta from that row

Comment: Okay, so are you actually asking a C# question at all, or is this *just* about SQL? If it's not about C# (i.e. you're not expecting any C# code in an answer), please remove the C# tag. You should also clarify the wording of the question.

Comment: no in need to manage in sql

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: i need to manage in sql

Comment: Right, so C# shouldn't be listed in your tags, as it's irrelevant to your question.

Comment: ok  thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this...

```
;WITH CTE_Result AS
(
SELECT 
         upw.IDUPW
        ,gig.IDGig
        ,gig.Number
        ,gig.DateCreated
        ,gig.DateRequired
        ,Originator.Originator
        ,lc.IDLifeCycle
        ,lc.LoggedById
        ,lc.OwnedByID
        ,lc.AssignedToID
        ,lc.LoggedOn
        ,lc.Detail
        ,f.IDFunction
        ,f.Name
        ,f.PastTenseFunction
        ,AssignedTo.AssignedBy
        ,LoggedBy.LoggedBy
        ,OwnedBy.OwnedBy 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lic.IDGIG ORDER BY loggedon DESC ) AS Row_lifecycle
    FROM [UserXProjectXWorkFlowUserGroup] upw
    INNER JOIN gig on gig.IDUPW= upw.IDUPW
    INNER JOIN lifecycle lc ON gig.IdGIG= lc.IDGIG     
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT concat(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as'AssignedBy' FROM [User] u WHERE u.IDUser = lc.AssignedToID) AssignedTo
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT concat(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as'LoggedBy' FROM [User] u WHERE u.IDUser = lc.LoggedByID) LoggedBy
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT  concat(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as'OwnedBy' FROM [User] u WHERE u.IDUser = lc.OwnedByID) OwnedBy
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT  concat(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as'Originator' FROM [User] u WHERE u.IDUser = upw.IDUser) Originator
    INNER JOIN levelXfunction lf ON lf.IDLevelXFunction= lc.IDLevelXFunction
    INNER JOIN [Function] f ON f.IDFunction = lf.IdFunction
    WHERE 
        gig.IDUPW= @IDUPW  
        AND upw.active=1 
        AND 1=(
                CASE WHEN @IDStatus!=0 AND f.IDFunctionXTab= @IDStatus THEN 1
                     WHEN @IDStatus=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
                 END
              )
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_Result
WHERE Row_lifecycle <=2 -- Change this number as per your requirement. e.g. 1 will get you the latest record, <=2 will get you latest and previous
```

Explanation:
          CTE_Results - is the derived table which can be used for your further query processing.

Now, as you need some data from 1st and some form second you should do a Self join on result set... something like

```
SELECT 
     U.IDUPW
    ,L.IDGig
    ,L.Number
    ,L.DateCreated
    ,L.DateRequired 

FROM
    CTE_Result U
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Result L ON U.IdGIG=L.IdGIG -- KEY COLUMNS 
WHERE U.Row_lifecycle <=2
```

Comment: I need some data from 1st row and some from second

Comment: Updated response... hope it helps!

Comment: its work for me but i am facing another problem . need get count of rows .first time i for all condition means with diff diff @IDStatats is this possible